# Scandit - Xamarin.forms iOS Implementation

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

We successfully implemented Scandit Parsing in Android, But we couldn’t complete the implementation in iOS(Xamarin forms).
We use below code to Parse the Scanned data.

```
Parser parser=new Parser();
var dicoptions = new NSDictionary("ParserDataFormat", ParserDataFormat.DLID);
 parser.SetOptions(dicoptions, new NSError());
ParserResult parserResult = parser.ParseString(code.Data, new NSError());
```

How can we set the pars the data format to parser ?
The iOS documentation provided with Objective c language and there is an option to set data format in Objective c and we couldn’t able to find the alternate in C#.

**Objective C Code**

```
SBSParser *parser = [picker parserForFormat:SBSParserDataFormatHIBC error:&err];
```

How we can write achieve above code in tamarin.Forms ?

Comment: Is this [sample](https://docs.scandit.com/barcode-scanner-sdk.html) useful for you?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT: The documentation is for Scanner, I implemented Scanner. I need to implement Scandit parser

Comment: It seems you have constructed the `Parser` using `parser.SetOptions(dicoptions, new NSError());`. If you want to achieve this on Forms I think you can use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/)